# GetSampleAsync does not fire in MediaStreamSource on WP7 device

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've been developing an audio app for Windows Phone 7 and up to this point have been using the WP7 emulator. The app uses a custom MediaStreamSource class to stream audio to a MediaElement.

On a real device, the custom MediaStreamSource completely fails. After calling MediaElement.Play(), the MediaStreamSource's GetSampleAsync method never gets called. It works just fine in the emulator.

I've started the app in the debugger (running on the device) and no exceptions get thrown anywhere.

I'm wondering if maybe my stream source is using a sample rate, bits per sample, or channel count that is not supported? I cannot find any documentation on what values *are* supported - however I find it hard to believe that my settings are not supported (44,100 Hz, 16 bits/sample, 2 channels).

Thoughts?

Comment: what is the type of the file? Try use blend encoder with mp3 and then wav. Codecs  in WP7 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462087%28VS.92%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that the Zune software interferes with the phone's media capabilities. The app will work on the device if you disconnect the device from the computer, or by using the WPConnect tool: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2010/11/03/tips-for-debugging-wp7-media-apps-with-wpconnect.aspx

Comment: What would be the answer for non wp7 devices like my pc? In a regular application it also never fires for me.